# Prometheus alert when counter has drop

Tags: alert, prometheus

I need to alert when there is a drop in a `counter` value in percentage.

I'm using `windows_iis_requests_total` metric from windows_exporter. And the goal is to spot when there is a drop in requests to the website. Currently I'm using

```
round(
    100 - (
      increase(windows_iis_requests_total[10m]) 
       / 
      increase(windows_iis_requests_total[10m] offset 1h)
    ) * 100
) > 50
```

Because it's a counter and not a gauge, I have to use it like this. But this expression produces a lot of "noise". It's often goes to 100% drop when the requests count is small in the first place. And the alert is going to self resolve itself if there is no requests at all for an hour.

Is there a better and more correct way to alert when there is a drop in website requests?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check functions like standard deviation for bette ranomaly detection.

A good read on this subject: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/23/anomaly-detection-using-prometheus/